# jquery accordion setting option after init

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery accordion.But setting some options after initialization is not working for me.
For eg :

```
$( "#accordId" ).accordion( "option", "animated", 'bounceslide' );
```

is not working.

But is is working for some other options like :

```
  $( "#accordId" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Can anyone suggest any reason? I am using jquery `1.6.2` and `jquery.ui.custom.js  1.8.16`.

Comment: You need UI Effects Core for a bounceslide, do you have that module?

Comment: Its working for me when I give it in the options while initializing.Only when I try to set it using the setter it is not working.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: You need the "Effects Core" js file from http://jqueryui.com/download to use the bounceslide animation

Comment: hello.. if it is due to lack of that dependency then the bounceslide wont work even when i add that option in the initializing code also rt? In that case it is working means it whould not be due to the absence of the dependency I think. Am I wright?

Comment: If it works in the initialization then yes, you already have the dependency

Comment: If so what else can be the reason it doesn't work? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.9.+ "bounceslide" is no longer a valid animation within accordion.
See: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/  for animate easing string names.